# Firefox’s Assert.jsm

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

According to the MDN docs, Firefox appears to have an [Assert.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Assert.jsm) module. Those docs say that you can use `Components.utils.import("resource://testing-common/Assert.jsm");` in your extension to use it. However, when I try that I get the following error:

```
Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) 
[nsIXPCComponents_Utils.import]"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"
```

The docs also says that this module requires Gecko 28. I tried it with Abrowser 33 (which is basically Firefox 33), so that shouldn’t be the problem.

I have succesfully imported other modules:

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm')
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm')
```

It might be worth noting that I tried this in a bootrapped extension, that doesn’t use the SDK. I’ve tried a bootstrap.js file with only the `Components.utils.import(...)` line in it, and the error is still thrown.

If I enter `resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm` (one of the modules that I managed to import) in the location bar, the source code of that module is shown. If I enter `resource://testing-common/Assert.jsm`, though, nothing at all happens!

What’s going on here?

(Edit: Since this question was written, the MDN docs linked to have been updated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue is that the URL `resource://testing-common/Assert.jsm` does not exist.

In Firefox 33.0 the correct URL for this module is: `resource://specialpowers/Assert.jsm`

While the [Assert.jsm page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Assert.jsm) claimed that it is available on Firefox 28, I did not find it in the Firefox release until 31.0. As of Firefox 31.0 it was at the `resource://specialpowers/Assert.jsm` URL.

Comment: Wow so cool how do you check sourcecodes @ certain versions of FF like this?

Comment: @Noitidart, this might be better as a question as comments limit space. See [Working with Mozilla source code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Source_Code). For extension work, I prefer to keep the contents of the 3 `omni.ja` files in a directory for each release in which I am interested. This allows quick searching (GUI or command-line) of exact files released with each version. I copy and expand the 3 `omni.ja` after I install each update, or [Firefox releases](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/). Then `find . -name Assert.jsm -print`.

Comment: Wow that is so awesome. I have to chat with you to learn how to do this some day.

Comment: do you know ctypes by any chance? im struggling with this over here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1108246